# MongoDB Unexpected end of JSON input, using python to scrape

Tags: python, json, mongodb

So im scraping fanfiction.net for story data, and get returned a dictionary. I dump the dictionary into my json file, and make sure that it is valid, then when i try and import the JSON file into MongoDB, it comes back as unexpected end of JSON input. Ive googled around, an nobody really seems to have an answer for this. I will attach a link to the whole file of data im trying to import, and have multiple files like it that i need to import. Also attached is the raw JSON i have to import:

```
{
    "id": "4391921",
    "canon": "Supernatural",
    "author_id": 3240,
    "title": "Light of Day, Dark of Moon",
    "lang": "English",
    "published": 1215966904,
    "chapter_names": [
        "Light of Day, Dark of Moon"
    ],
    "genres": [
        "Drama",
        "Family"
    ],
    "canon_type": [
        "TV Shows"
    ],
    "rated": "Fiction  T",
    "num_words": 3441,
    "num_reviews": 38,
    "num_favs": 79,
    "num_follows": 11,
    "status": "Complete"
},
{
    "id": "4391909",
    "canon": "Supernatural",
    "author_id": 3240,
    "title": "A Year and a Day",
    "lang": "English",
    "published": 1215966494,
    "chapter_names": [
        "A Year and a Day"
    ],
    "genres": [
        "Drama",
        "Hurt/Comfort"
    ],
    "canon_type": [
        "TV Shows"
    ],
    "rated": "Fiction  M",
    "num_words": 32830,
    "num_reviews": 10,
    "num_favs": 46,
    "num_follows": 3,
    "status": "Complete"
},
```

https://github.com/ethanbreck/fanfiction-api-scraper/tree/master/data/user_write

Answer (score 0):

Same error importing with Compass. Use Studio 3T instead!! That worked for me.